# Pivoting Values from a column into rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I'm looking to use python to pivot values from one row into new columns, and then combine the rows.  For example:

| Name | Random info | Role | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Yada | Owner | Bob |
| A | Yada | Approver | Jimmy |
| B | Nada | Owner | Sally |
| B | Nada | Approver | Susie |

Would become this:

| Name | Random Info | Owner | Approver |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Yada | Bob | Jimmy |
| B | Nada | Sally | Susie |

What's the best way to do this?

I tried using the pivot functions available in pandas, but I kept getting different errors because I don't think my data is structured correctly compared to what the function is expecting.

Comment: Something like `df.pivot(index=["Name", "Random info"], columns="Role", values="Name.1")` should work (mind the duplicate column label `Name`)

Comment: Classic SO post on pivoting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe